# TYPO3 extBase Labels in Controller

Tags: typo3, extbase

I am using **TYPO3 6.2 CMS** version. 
I want to use dynamic labels in controller but I can't find a way.

I tried with below one but it's taking to much time for loading.

```
$GLOBALS['LANG']
->sL('LLL:EXT:arzte/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tx_extension_name');
```

Any other idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, for label in extbase you can use

> $GLOBALS['LANG']->sL('LLL:EXT:arzte/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:tx_extension_name');

but somehow it's not working at all.

I have found solution may your help:

> \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('your_label_key','your_extensionName');

It's work fine for me try it :)

Comment: I tried with this and it's working. 

You save my day. Thank you so much.